# How to create a Combo box and display their values in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to this and i need this for a course that i'm making. This sounds like this: Create a combo box. Create an element div with an arbitrary id. After creating the combo box define the event that will call the function. This function must contain the code that in the moment you modify the element selected from the drop down list it will write the value inside of the div that we made with the arbitrary id.

sorry guys, it's my first time on stackoverflow. Towkir you are you are absolutely right. I have tryed this, but from here, i get stucked

```html
html>
<body>

<form>
  <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Pineapple</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
  </select>
</form>
<div id="demo"><p></p></div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var i = x.selectedIndex;
    document.getElementById("demo").firstChild.innerHTML; = x.options[i].text;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try to write something?

Comment: Do you need to create the combo box and the div in javascript or do you already have them in html?

Comment: Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/utnr6kx4/) you can work from

Comment: Please try to share what you tried. Stackoverflow is not a coding service. Thanks

Comment: sorry guys, it's my first time on stackoverflow.  Towkir you are you are absolutely right. I have tryed this, but from here, i get stucked...

Comment: Dominique Fortin i already have them in html

Comment: @Ovidiu91 After `.firstChild.innerHTML` remove the semicolon and the code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var i = x.selectedIndex;
  document.getElementById("demo").firstChild.innerHTML = x.options[i].text;
}
```